# Sub-sites disappeared from Global Navigation & top navigation tab after new sites created

Tags: 2010, navigation, sub-site, top-link-bar

In our SharePoint 2010 systme, we have 50+ sub-sites that all have inherit the same navigation as our parent site.  We have about 1/2 of the sites hidden.  When we created 3 new sites 2 of the existing sites disappeared from the Global Navigation list and the tabs disappeared from the top link bar.  We have the maximum number of dynamic items to show w/in this level of navigation set to well above the # of sub-sites we have and that matches the same on each of the sub-site levels.
Why did the existing 2 sites disappear and how do we get them back on the Global Navigation list and the tabs to reappear in the top link bar? 
How do we prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Where these the 2 oldest? Or the first or last 2 by position or alphabetically? Several SharePoint features have numeric limits. I think there were a maximum of 50 views that could be listed at one time in SP 2010. You added one more and the last alphabetically disappeared.

Comment: These were the last sites on the Global Nav list that is sorted alphabetically.  We did further testing in a test data base by adding new test sites and again the last sites disappeared from the bottom of the list.  From there we started deleting sites and the sites that disappeared earlier reappeared. Are you saying you think there is a max of 50 sites that can be in the Glob Nav List?  We have exactly 50 with quite a few that are hidden but found that showing or hiding does not have an impact. Can this be increased? Do you think this could this be a memory capacity issue?

Comment: >  Are you saying you think there is a max of 50 sites that can be in the Glob Nav List?  --- that's been a pattern we have seen before. You can add as many as you want, but a max of 50 "displayable" items. I don't think it can be increased, and it's not a memory limit. The alternate is to create a web part or custom JavaScript solution to display the site list.

Comment: Your comments have been very helpful, thank you!